# Get Rid of Extra Spaces At The Beginning Of Each Line When Writing Text To Log File Via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I use the code below to output an error log. For the life of me, I can't seem to find a reason that every line written to the log file has exactly 14 spaces added to the front end of it.  I'd rather not have the spaces there if it can be helped.  I've tried opening the file as `Binary Access Write` as well as having tried `Write #fNum` and `Put #fNum` (These get rid of the spaces but seem to add a `CRLF` and/or quotations around the line, which I don't want).  Can someone help me understand what I'm missing

```
Sub LogError(ByVal eCode As String, ByVal eDesc As String, ByVal eSource As String, ByVal eSub As String)
'                  Error Number           Error Description      Error Source             Sub/Function Error Occurred In
    Dim fNum As Integer
    Dim fName As String
    Dim eRecord As String
        eRecord = "Date: " & Date & " # User: " & Environ("Username") & " # System: " & Environ("ComputerName") & _
                    " # Error Code: " & eCode & " # Descripton: " & eDesc & " # Source: " & eSource & " # Calling Routine: " & eSub
        fName = Environ("Temp") & "\TDB_Error_" & Replace(CStr(Date), "/", "_") & ".log"
        Select Case Dir(fName)
            Case ""
                fNum = FreeFile()
'                Open fName For Binary Access Write As fNum
'                Put #fNum, , eRecord
                Open fName For Output As fNum
                Print #fNum, , eRecord
                Close #fNum
            Case Else
                fNum = FreeFile()
                Open fName For Append As fNum
                Print #fNum, , eRecord
                Close #fNum
        End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Try getting rid of one comma like this `Print #fNum, eRecord`.

Comment: @BrianMStafford That did it.  ty!  So that I can understand better what is going on, can you explain why that made a difference?

Comment: I'm not sure why you got 14 spaces because the command only has 2 parms like I showed.  You can use a semi-colon to pass multiple pieces of data so it must have gotten confused by the comma.

Comment: @BrianMStafford going back and looking, I can only assume I was using for parameter format for the `Put #` statement without realizing it.  Thanks again